Getting a "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'destroyed')" on a store Dispatch
I'm using Angular 17 with Ngrx
I have a details page protected by a Guard that checks if the element exists in the store or explicitly dispatches a 'get by id' action.
  /**
   * check Store Function
   * @param requestId Request ID
   */
  checkStore(requestId: string): Observable<boolean> {
    this.store.dispatch(
      RequestLifeCycleActions.LoadRequestLifeCycle({
        action: RequestQueryActions.REQUESTS,
        requestId,
      })
    );
    return this.store.select(requestLifeCycleSelectors.selectIfRequestLifeCycleListLoaded).pipe(
      filter((loaded) => loaded),
      take(1)
    );
  }

Sometimes, when accessing the page multiple times (for example, selecting one element, then going back, and then selecting another one), it may result in a "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'destroyed')" error with no content appearing, even though the data is successfully loaded in the store.

I tried disabling the guard and dispatching directly without a check from the page component itself, but I still receive the same behavior.

Please provide the line request-exsits.guard.ts:47

Hello enno.void. The code I provided was the portion where the error had occurred, and the line 47 was indeed where the dispatch function exists
